# increment date ORA - 00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sqlplus

I have a defined date in my script

```
define REPORT_DATE = to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy')
```

when I try to increment it

```
select *
from STG_PREP_CHARGES_PLAN SPCP
where &REPORT_DATE + 1 < SPCP.NEXT_CHARGE_DATE
```

I get ORA - 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Is there a function like add_months, but for days?

SPCP.NEXT_CHARGE_DATE is a date

```
desc STG_PREP_CHARGES_PLAN
Name                   Null Type          
---------------------- ---- ------------- 
NEXT_CHARGE_DATE            DATE
```

UPDATE

It's strange. I changed the date to to_date('06112016','ddmmyyyy') and then back and it started working. Have no idea what it was.

UPDATE2
Found what the problem is. I just had to select all query before running it.

Comment: What if you edit your code in `to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy') + 1 < SPCP.NEXT_CHARGE_DATE`?

Comment: The point being, is `SPCP.NEXT_CHARGE_DATE` a date, or something else (like a number or a string, similar to `05112016`)?

Comment: Works OK at my side...  As mathguy pointed out, it may be the case that your `spcp.next_charge_date` is not a `date` nor a `timestamp` value.

Comment: Please add the code context (some lines before and after)

Comment: @Ale This to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy') + 1 < SPCP.NEXT_CHARGE_DATE works, but I use REPORT_DATE in a lot of places in my query. I don't want to write it like that.

Comment: @math It's a date.

Comment: Your code as specified works fine for me. There's something else going on here.

Comment: Please extract the DDL of the table and put it into your question.

Comment: @nop updated the post

Answer (score 2):

The issue here seems to be in the type of `NEXT_CHARGE_DATE`.

For example, if I check a variable like yours against a `date`, I have no problems:

```
SQL> define REPORT_DATE = to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy');
SQL> select 1 from dual where sysdate = &report_date;
old   1: select 1 from dual where sysdate = &report_date
new   1: select 1 from dual where sysdate = to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy')

no rows selected
```

No matter if I add a day to the variable value, it still works:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual where sysdate = &report_date +1;
old   1: select 1 from dual where sysdate = &report_date +1
new   1: select 1 from dual where sysdate = to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy') +1

no rows selected
```

If I try to compare the variable with an object that is not a `date`, say a `number`, I have your error:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual where 1 = &report_date +1;
old   1: select 1 from dual where 1 = &report_date +1
new   1: select 1 from dual where 1 = to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy') +1
select 1 from dual where 1 = to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy') +1
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

No matter if I remove the `+1`, I still get the same error, because the issue is in the types of the objects you are comparing, not in the way you add a day to your variable:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual where 1 = &report_date;
old   1: select 1 from dual where 1 = &report_date
new   1: select 1 from dual where 1 = to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy')
select 1 from dual where 1 = to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy')
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

To solve, you should check the type of `NEXT_CHARGE_DATE` and add some `to_char`, `to_number` or `to_date` to your code to compare objects of the same type.

With a `date` column, everything works fine for me (Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production):

```
SQL> create table STG_PREP_CHARGES_PLAN ( NEXT_CHARGE_DATE date);

Table created.

SQL> define REPORT_DATE = to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy');
SQL> select *
  2  from STG_PREP_CHARGES_PLAN SPCP
  3  where &REPORT_DATE + 1 < SPCP.NEXT_CHARGE_DATE;
old   3: where &REPORT_DATE + 1 < SPCP.NEXT_CHARGE_DATE
new   3: where to_date('05112016','ddmmyyyy') + 1 < SPCP.NEXT_CHARGE_DATE

no rows selected
```